# Função de Go com parâmetros

Tags: funções, sintaxe, golang

Me deparei com a função a seguir em um *framework* de Map Reduce, mas não entendi a sintaxe dela.

```
func (fc *FlowContext) newNextDataset(shardSize int, dType reflect.Type) (ret *Dataset) {
    ret = NewDataset(fc, dType)
    if dType != nil {
        ret.SetupShard(shardSize)
    }
    return
}
```

Por que temos três parenteses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro par é usado para receber uma parâmetro que é tratado de forma especial. Isso é chamado *method receiver*. É uma forma muito semelhante a como as linguagens tratam métodos onde há um parâmetro implícito que é o objeto `this`, mas no caso de Go é recebido de forma explícita. Sendo separado fica mais fácil o compilador identificar a condição especial. Assim o método é aplicado apenas a um tipo específico. Dessa forma você pode chamar a função como um método, ou seja, você chama o método de acordo com o objeto em uso. Se pensar bem faz até mais sentido que em outras linguagens porque você trata na definição o parâmetro que é especial e no local que ele é usado na chamada, ainda que a sintaxe fique meio esquisita.

O segundo par é usado para estabelecer uma tupla de parâmetros, igual a todas as linguagens.

O terceiro par é usado para agrupar o tipo do retorno da função que sempre vem depois do nome e parâmetros da função. Ele é usado porque no caso o tipo é composto por um ponteiro e tem o nome do parâmetro, assim evita ambiguidade e garante que é uma coisa só.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma dica pra quem conhece C# e VB: Aquela sintaxe é tipo um [extension method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) para o tipo `FlowContext`, dai dá pra chamar `flowContext.newNextDataSet(p1, p2)` em vez de `newNextDataSet(flowContext, p1, p2)`.

Comment: Isso, é bem parecido.

Answer (score 1):

Quando estudei essa sintaxe, para fixar, entendi que eram métodos relacionados a um determinado objeto.  Nesse exemplo tempos a struct FlowContext. Após instanciar essa classe em um objeto será possível chamar esse método diretamente.

Então vamos ao exemplo:

```
var obj FlowContext

//Veja que chamo o método através do próprio objeto declarado acima.
objDataSet := obj.newNextDataset(1, dType)
```

Tem um trecho na documentação que explica esse tipo de sintaxe ;)
https://tour.golang.org/methods/3

Mas ficou mais claro pra vc?

[]'s